# Is this a case of javascript comma operator

Tags: javascript

Please see [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/brush.js#L370) code from d3.js

```
if (y1 < y0) t = y0, y0 = y1, y1 = t;
```

has this anything to do with [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), in the sense of returning/assigning the last value, or equivalent to

```
if (y1 < y0) {
  t = y0;
  y0 = y1;
  y1 = t;
}
```

I was more worried about, anything tricky happening here by relying on the order of operation.

Comment: That is completely correct, comma operator used to be more concise, leading to faster download, and less memory footprint.

Comment: @ArifBurhan you should avoid making such claims unless you can support them.

Comment: Nothing tricky, just a simple left-to-right evaluation of each expression. The comma operator has the lowest precedence of all operators, so there should be few worries there. Personally, if I wanted it on a single line, I'd write it like this: `if (y1 < y0) {t = y0; y0 = y1; y1 = t}` Only a single extra character. Makes me wonder if maybe they auto-format their code, and the tool forces the semicolon version onto separate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the first snippet uses the comma operator and both snippets are equivalent, as the comma operator evaluates from left to right.

The comma operator is used in your snippet to put multiple *assignments* into a single *statement*, so they are all governed by the preceding `if` and a few characters (`{` and `}`) can be saved.

Not sure if this is worth doing manually, but minifiers typically do this kind of optimization (and it adds up)